# Send data beetween two instance of the same component anugular 5

Tags: angular, angular-components

I just started to learn Angular 4 and I have a question about components.
How I can send data between two different component instance

Comment: Your question is too broad and already has an answer in the documentation.

Comment: can you give me a link. note that this is not a normal component, it is a dynamic component created two times, and i want to pass data from one to other

Comment: Under [component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), and the fact that they're both the same component is irrelevant, all of the solutions proposed in the documentation do apply to your case.

Comment: Ok, I will see, note I have already searched my case, but I didn't find a solution

Comment: I understand, documentation can be pretty long to read. I've been coding for two years with it, that's why I know it rather well. Don't forget to use the research field on the top right corner, it's very powerful (try typing "intercation", see how it behaves)

Comment: To guide you in the right direction, you should look up to what are Presentation / Smart components. I guess you need to have a top-level `smart` component that will manage the data, and that will be the link with your two `presentation` components with  the help of Inputs / Outputs. You could also use a service but you should try the first case beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Components can interact with each other based on following scenarios:

1. Pass data from parent to child with input binding
2. Intercept input property changes with a setter
3. Intercept input property changes with ngOnChanges()
4. Parent listens for child event
5. Parent interacts with child via local variable
6. Parent calls an @ViewChild()
7. Parent and children communicate via a service

[Link](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction) to understand in more detail